# Images and icons for mobile web?

Tags: image, html, mobile

Lately i have been thinking about what would be the best way to handle images and icons (a graphic link arrow for instance) in mobile development when there is alot of different resolutions out there (iPhone 3, iPhone 4, iPad 2, iPad 3, Android devices etc).

We are talking HTML5 web development, not a stand alone app. But sites targeted to mobile devices, so not a cross site (responsive).

I know you could target the devices based on resolution with CSS3, but still - it does not seem like a perfect solution.

What about SVG or HTML5 canvas - could this be used somehow? What are you doing do make your mobile site look nice and crisp on every device?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the framework jQueryMobile.
The documentation of it is in this link http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/

I hope it help you.

Comment: Not quite sure how this would help with image/icon scaling etc.?

Comment: When you download jQueryMobile you have a css file named: " jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" and there are many styles for different elements can be used in your application(navbar, button,icon,...) So search into this file 'ui-icon' for the style of icons

Comment: Maybe you are misunderstanding my question or i am misunderstanding yours :) I dont want to use a "template" (which jQuery mobile use, but you can make your own template, i know). As far as i know, jQuery mobile does not help you with scaling your images and/or icons to apper crisp on every device?